# Django - models.py - Does get_absolute_url function take conditions?

Tags: python, django, url, django-models

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    '''Category for men's and women's items'''
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=[
        (1, 'Women'),
        (2, 'Men'),
    ], default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_gender_display() + ' ' + self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if # condition: more than 1 value passed from url
            return reverse('boutique:category', kwargs={'gender': self.get_gender_display(), 'category_pk': self.pk})
        else:  
            return reverse('boutique:show-all', kwargs={'gender': self.get_gender_display()})
```

***Question***: how to work out the logic for `get_absolute_url` function to work more dynamically? Or is it not supposed to work dynamically? In the if statement above, I want to place a condition which checks how many values passed from url, so that it can decide which view to render. Is it possible? or should I just create `get_FOO_url()` function separately for rendering each view with different values passing in from url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the model itself does not know anything about the a request, it's not possible without any help.

I personally prefer https://pypi.org/project/django-middleware-global-request/ it was designed for exactly that purpose.

```
from django_global_request.middleware import get_request

class TestModel(models.Model):

    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        request = get_request()

        if request.GET.get('whatever'):
            return ...
        else:
            return ...
```

You just need to make sure, you could still access this method without any available request. So make sure it's fail safe and has a fallback in case of the absence of a request (like in a shell, upgrade, etc.)